# $geoNear maxDistance limitation to ~200km

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

When I try to use $geoNear to get documents near a Point it works well until 200km.
If I set maxDistance to anything greater than 200*1000 the number of results I get no longer changes.

```
db.posts.aggregate([ 
  { $geoNear: { 
      near: { 
        type: "Point", 
        coordinates: [-123.1207, 49.2827] 
      }, 
      distanceField: "dist.calculated", 
      num: 100000, maxDistance: 200*1000, 
      includeLocs: "dist.location", 
      spherical: true 
    }
  }, 
  {$count: "count"} 
])
```

Is this a limitation of $geoNear or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you also get the same count if you leave out `maxDistance` entirely?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I was just adding it so that I can find roughly at what distance the results stop changing. It is an assumption that there is a limitation but I dont know if that is for sure.